# In Ubuntu (Or perhaps other distros) how can I highlight text in a terminal window and insert it to the cursor?

Tags: linux, command-line

I used to work with a colleague who would often use the mouse to highlight text in a terminal window. Perhaps output from a previous command etc. Then would press a single key on the keyboard to insert it to the cursor at the prompt. I haven't used linux in a long time so cannot remember how to do this.

Comment: I thought it was the insert key but this isn't working for me - perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The middle mouse button does that. If your keyboard doesn't have the Paste key, try Shift + Insert.

Comment: In Terminal, highlight with mouse, and Ctrl-Shift-Cto copy, Ctrl-Shift-V to paste.